# `RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction` when trying to save an object with Spring JPA and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to save an object in my MySQL DB by using Spring JPA.

That's the error I get:

```
[nio-8088-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
[org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction]
```

That's where I'm trying to save my object:

```java
@Override
public RegistrationV1Response registerUser(@Valid RegistrationV1Request registrationV1Request) {

    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstname(registrationV1Request.getFirstname());
    user.setLastname(registrationV1Request.getLastname());
    user.setUsername(registrationV1Request.getUsername());
    user.setEmail(registrationV1Request.getEmail());
    user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(registrationV1Request.getPassword()));
    user.setActive(true);

    userRepository.save(user);

    return new RegistrationV1Response().withUser(user);
}
```

The `UserRepository`:

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    public User findFirstByUsername(String username);
}
```

The `User` class:

```java
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends Entity {

    @Column(name = "firstname", nullable = false, length = 100)
    @NotEmpty()
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "lastname", nullable = false, length = 100)
    @NotEmpty()
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 100)
    @NotEmpty()
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 100)
    @NotEmpty()
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 100)
    @NotEmpty()
    @Email()
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty()
    private boolean active;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = true, length = 250)
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Post.class, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Post> posts;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isActive() { return active; }

    public void setActive(boolean active) { this.active = active; }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<Post> getPosts() { return posts; }

    public void setPosts(List<Post> posts) { this.posts = posts; }
}
```

The `Post` class:

```java
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post extends Entity {

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "text", nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty()
    private String text;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    private User user;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Reading from the DB work's without any problems just save (insert / update) doesn't work.

I just read on a similar issue that I need to add the `@Transational` property to the method. I did this and it's still not working. Also the other possible solutions / statements of similar issues aren't working. They're mostly about missconfigured relations or something and that's not the problem in my case I think.

Comment: Could you please update the whole world error trace?

Comment: That's everything I get on the console. The message before is from the Dispatcher Servlet that the initialization has completed.

Comment: This is generic error message, could you please add the –debug or –trace arguments on the command line? -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--logging.level.org.springframework=TRACE